# How to achieve synchronization in database level?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm developing an airline reservation system as my semester project. Here, when one customer books a seat in a specific aircraft, I need to prevent another customer from booking that seat at the same time. I know how to do this in back-end level using synchronization. I need to know whether there is a way to do this in database level. If so, could you please point me in some direction

Comment: ok. lets say only prevent from booking the same seat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create unique constraint for 2 columns in table  like (flight_id, seat_id)

Comment: could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: I assume that you store information about booking information about flight in some table like reservation, when you put information like id, flight_id, seat_id, user_id etc. So if you add unique constraint on two columns (flight_id and seat_id) it will be impossible to add reservation for two different users for same seat -> the database will throw exception in this situation.